# как менять массивы местами в зависимости от ситуации

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 массива, нужно менять их местами, когда ширина экрана меняется. Так как я начинающий, я использовал элементарный `if else` сработал правда, но теперь оба массива работают  (один задает `marginleft` другой `marginright`).
Помогите пожалуйста.

вот код

```
   var margin =["-150px","-140","-130px","-120px",
                "-110px","-100px","-90px","-80px",
                "-70px","-60px"];

   var marginScreen =["200px","190px","180px","170px",
                      "160px","150px","140px","130px",
                      "120px","110px","100px","90px"];

  var screen = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (screen <= 1080) {
    margin = marginScreen; 
     withAp.style.marginLeft = marginScreen[nextOne]; //nextOne это переменная для массива которое тут не важен..
     withAp.style.opacityForLeft = opacityForLeft[nextOne];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создается отдельная переменная (`marginSetCurrent`), которая в зависимости от условий указывает на один из массивов. При этом сами массивы не модифицируются.

```
var marginSet1 = [-150, -140, -130, -120, -110, -100, -90, -80, -70, -60]
  , marginSet2 = [200, 190, 180, 170, 160, 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100, 90]
  , screen = document.documentElement.clientWidth
  , marginSetCurrent = screen <= 1080 ? marginSet2 : marginSet1;
withAp.style.marginLeft = marginSetCurrent[nextOne] + 'px';
```

Comment: а я не знал что можно так с запятыми писать .Спасибо большое за время потраченную и за обьяснения

Answer (score 0):

Чувак, если возможно, то лучше юзай медиа-запросы в css для установки нужных стилей под соответствующую ширину экрана.
Например,

```
//установка маргина при ширине экрана больше 760px
@media (min-width: 760px){
 #withAp{
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
}

//установка маргина при ширине экрана меньше 760px
@media (max-width: 760px){
 #withAp{
  margin: 0 20px;
 }
}
```

Comment: тут при скролле картинка должна двигаться если пикселей больше 1080 то она начинает свою позицию  с право если меньше то  центра и двигается .Такое невозможно реализовать при помощи медиа-запросов.